# checking whether array values exist in an table with another table

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

Here am checking an array values exist or not with another table and if exist it should produce the output.
Here is my array value which looks like this 
[image]

the code i written is here

```
<?php if(array_search($v_employee->user_id,array_column($salary_info, 'user_id'))) {?>      
  <?php echo $v_employee->fullname; ?>

  <?php } else { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/payroll/view_payment_details/<?php echo $v_employee->user_id . '/' . $payment_month ?>"title="View" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal_lg"><?php echo $v_employee->fullname; ?></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

it doesn't produce any result.please help me to solve.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

array_column can't read object
try this one

```
<?php 

$salary_info_arr=json_decode(json_encode(array_filter($salary_info)),true); //changed

if(array_search($v_employee->user_id,array_column($salary_info_arr, 'user_id'))) {?>      
  <?php echo $v_employee->fullname; ?>

  <?php } else { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/payroll/view_payment_details/<?php echo $v_employee->user_id . '/' . $payment_month ?>"title="View" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal_lg"><?php echo $v_employee->fullname; ?></a>
 <?php } ?> 

 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: getting this two errors 1.`Message: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given,`.2.`Message: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Comment: @user_777 I change in `$salary_info_arr=json_decode(json_encode(array_filter($salary_info)),true); `  please try this.
if still getting error then change in your old code like `if(array_search($v_employee->user_id,array_column((array)$salary_info, 'user_id')))`